# Microsoft-Teams Tab General Settings

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-teams

I am creating a custom tab for Microsoft Teams. Is it possible to configure some general settings for the application. I want to configure them on the admin page of Office 365 or when adding the application to Teams(not through manifest file).

Is that possible and if yes how?

Comment: You can configure your Tab's configurable settings in [Configuration page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-configuration). Could you please share more details about these settings?

Comment: I want to configure general settings such as "Issuer", "Audiance", "Secret", which I want to configure only when adding the application to a team. Afterwards I use the Configuration page for configuring each tab, but the idea is that the general settings remain the same for the whole team.

Comment: Are these setting applicable only for one Team or all teams in tenant? In both the cases, you need to persist these settings. For the first time when there are no settings associated with teams or tenant then you show General settings configuration page while adding tab. For sub sequent tab, check if you have settings persisted and show tab configuration page directly.

Comment: So, there are no other settings to be configured rather than the one on the configuration page when adding a tab?
If so, is there a workaround that I can make in order to achieve the goal.

Comment: You could show config page which just allows user to save without making any modifications to settings. You can optionally keep simple page which shows your app details. Please have a look at [Create the configuration page for your Microsoft Teams configurable tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-configurable) docs so that you could implement what suits your requirement.

Comment: This does not solve my problem, since I want to allow only the owner that is adding the application into the team to specify the "Secret" for example, and therefore whenever a member adds a tab to configure a name for tab and other settings, but not to be ersponsible for specifying a "Secret" everytime when adding a tab.